# Get Face Angle values info via python

Tags: python, mesh, faces, bmesh

I would like to get face angle information (same information you can see when "Mesh Display->Face Info: Angle" is enabled.

I want to loop over the mesh to find triangles that fit certain angle thresholds (for example: select all triangles that have 2 interior angles below 10 degrees).

I tried using the built in function (BMVert calc_edge_angle) but this only works on detached triangles.

I found this to be good code for iterating over selected faces/edges:
[How to get a list of edges of current face in bpy](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/6727/how-to-get-a-list-of-edges-of-current-face-in-bpy)

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: it would be helpful (if not a requirement) to provide what you have so far in order to assist others to help you.  You can format code as text or upload a test blend file to https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: Not sure that `BMVert.calc_edge_angle(...)` and the apex angle of a triangle are the same thing. All edge angles on the cube are 90 all on a grid 180.  Its the angle between the two face normals adjoining the edge.  Whereas for three verts of triangle ABC the "interior" angles are `AB.angle(BC)` and `BC.angle(CA)` etc.  (where vector AB = vert coordinate B - A)